# Select rows where user id column has only specified string

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint

I have extracted a spreadsheet of all users with Full Control access on our SharePoint farm using PowerShell.

Now, from that list I am trying get a list of sites where only the SP admins are exclusive owners. I loaded the extracted spreadsheet in Access and am writing queries to generate various reports.

All user IDs for one SP site are stored in a cell in a column called `UserID` and they are separated by semi-colons: `User1; User2;` and so on.

```
SiteName Url                UserID                
-------- ---------------    ----------------             
Site1    https://test.com   User1;User2;User3;
Site2    https://test2.com  User1;User3;User5;...;User50;
```

I have a table with a UserID column.

Ex: User1, 2 and 3 are the SP admins

```
Row 1 has UserID column values: "User1; User2; User3"
Row 2: "User2; User3;"
Row 3: "User1; User4; .... ;User50;"
Row 4: "User1; User2; User4;... ;User25;"
Row 5: "User3;"
```

I am trying to design a query where only rows containing either `User1`, `User2` or `User3` exist in that cell. Which basically means only Rows 1, 2 and 5 return in the results. `Row3` and `Row4` should **not** return in the result because it has users other than `User1`, `2` and `3` in their cells.

Using `LIKE` doesn't help this because it returns every row where it finds one of these users. I cannot use `NOT LIKE` to exclude the remaining users because a lot of rows have over 30 users listed in a cell having full control access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces (if they are there) inside the `UserID` column make the string manipulation of the column more complex.
The idea is to replace `'User1'`, `'User2'` and `'User3'` with an empty string and then remove all semicolons and all spaces.
If what is left has `length = 0` then this row contains only `'User1'` or `'User2'` or `'User3'` or combinations of them:

```
select * from tablename
where
len(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(userid, 'User1', ''), 'User2', ''), 'User3', ''), ';',''), ' ', '')) = 0
```

Comment: @LeeMac it's the only idea that came up with this kind of data. I tried to construct the NotSPAdmins idea that you have but no luck with the join and the like operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to acquire the set of all UserIDs which are **not** SP admins, then you could use a query such as the following  to acquire the rows you require:

```
select t1.* 
from YourTable t1 left join NotSPAdmins t2 on t1.UserID like '*' & t2.UserID & '*'
where t2.UserID is null
```